# python call method from different class

Tags: python, class, wxwidgets

I am trying to call a method (OnOpen) that resides in one class (Main), from another class (prefWindow). I am using wx python for a GUI.
The problem is that whenever I try to use this parent.OnOpen, it errors saying it is not defined.
I am by no means a python expert, and only started it recently.

```
class Main(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
       *more code here*

    def OnOpen(self,e): 
      global dirname
      dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file to open", self.dirname, "", "*.apk", wx.OPEN) #open the dialog box to open file

class prefWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id)  
        self.initPref()

    def initPref(self):
       browseBtn = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Browse")
       self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, parent.OnOpen, browseBtn)
```

Thanks.

Comment: There's something missing in your code snippet also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use class inheritance and make your own base class:

```
class MyWindow(wx.Frame):
    def OnOpen(self,e): 
      global dirname
      dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a file to open", self.dirname, "", "*.apk", wx.OPEN) #open the dialog box to open file

class Main(MyWindow):
    ...

class prefWindow(MyWindow):
    ...
```

Now the `onOpen()` method will be available as well as all the methods from `wx.Frame` on instances of `Main` and `prefWindow`.